# Solidity struct array

Tags: solidity

I'm running into a problem with solidity with structures containing arrays, can you help me see what I'm missing?Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 struct Info {
    uint a;
    uint256 b;
    uint[] data;
}

mapping(address => Info) infos;

function set() public {
    infos[msg.sender].a = 1;
    infos[msg.sender].b = 2;
    infos[msg.sender].data.push(3);
}

function get() public {
      infos[msg.sender].a; //yes It is equal to 1
      infos[msg.sender].b; //yes It is equal to 2
      infos[msg.sender].data[0]; //The problem here is that anyone calling this function can read data[0]=3
}
```

Comment: My problem is that when someone calls set() and anyone else calls get(), data[0] returns 3, which is weird

Answer (score 0):

So this works as you said. you pushed value `3` to the array and it returns value `3` at 0 index of the array. if you want data array has 3 elements you should push 3 times a value maybe 0.

Comment: Maybe my demo gave you the wrong idea, but I already know where I went wrong.
View-decorated functions should not use msg.sender, it is empty address!